# How to change switched outlets to half switched and half always hot

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I'm trying to make my two switched outlets to be half hot. I tried breaking the brass tab on outlet 1 to accomplish that but that didn't work. It only made one receptacle work from the switch while the other didn't work at all. It also caused outlet 2 to not work at all. I don't know if it's the current wiring or if it's just not possible at all. Help please!!  [image: Light switch wiring][image: Outlet 1 wiring][image: Outlet 2 wiring]

Comment: Briefly -- it appears that you do not have enough wires between the switch and the outlets to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Is running new cables between the boxes involved an option?

Comment: Running new cable isn't an option.

Comment: Would it be possible to just the outlet with the two blacks always hot without running new wire?

Comment: Probably you have only switched hots in the boxes for the receptacles. You do not have an always hot wire. Therefore you cannot have one half of the duplex receptacles switched and the other half always hot.

Comment: You're right. The only always hot is in the light switch box.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have broken off the tabs on the hot sides of the receptacles unless you had an always hot in the receptacle boxes.

If you want to restore the existing function without buying new receptacles, you can

(1) make a pair of pigtails with black or red insulated wire and connect to the two hot screws and connect the switched hot to that with a wire nut or

(2) make a loop with the one switched hot wire over to the other screw and strip off a little of the insulation, or

(3) if the receptacle has back wiring secured by a screw (not just push in) you can connect a jumper (insulated black or red) in the back holes

Comment: Thanks. I already have extra receptacles to replace these with.

Comment: Our house has one switched receptacle in each bedroom. This is a "cost saving" alternative to a switched ceiling fixture. !#$%&@#! . . . In one room we had an electrician add a ceiling fixture and run a cable to  the existing switch to power it and control it.  (At the time I had no idea how to fish a wire into an existing switch box.) We disconnected the receptacle from the switch and now the receptacle is unswitched, always hot.